# How to go to "next page" on a html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a browser game where I'm placing buildings on a grid. I have a HUD on the bottom of the canvas that has pictures of all the buildings.

The HUD doesn't have enough space to hold all the buildings, so my plan is to have an arrow -> that user can click on to go to the "next page" of buildings, or maybe implement some sort of scrolling mechanism to move to a new segment of the HUD bar?

This probably isn't a big issue but since my HUD only covers a portion of the screen at the bottom of the canvas, I would only move that, and not the entire canvas.

Anyone who's implemented a similar mechanic want to share some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I think you could emulate a viewport by translating everything in your HUD when the user clicks on the arrow :

```
building1.x += 50;
building2.x += 50;
```

and so on. But then you'd have to hide the buildings that are overflowing.